# Select hierarchical data without using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductHierarchy]
(
    [ProductHierarchyID] INT NOT NULL
          PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [ProductID] INT NOT NULL ,
    [ParentProductID] INT NULL
);
```

with this data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] ([ProductID], [ParentProductID])
VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 4), (7, 4);
```

Now, I can do hierarchical query with a CTE like this:

```
WITH [CTE_Products] ([ProductID], [ParentProductID], [ProductLevel]) AS 
(
    SELECT
        [ProductID],
        [ParentProductID],
        0 AS [ProductLevel]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ProductHierarchy]
    WHERE 
        [ParentProductID] IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
        [pn].[ProductID],
        [pn].[ParentProductID],
        [p1].[ProductLevel] + 1
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] AS [pn]
    INNER JOIN 
        [CTE_Products] AS [p1] ON [p1].[ProductID] = [pn].[ParentProductID]
)
SELECT  
    [ProductID],
    [ParentProductID],
    [ProductLevel]
FROM 
    [CTE_Products]
ORDER BY 
    [ParentProductID];
```

But how can I reach the same goal with one SQL statement without using a CTE? Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible with your data model (although there are other ways of representing hierarchical data). These types of queries are one reason why recursive CTEs were invented/added to the language.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?? You obviously know how to write the CTE, and the CTE approach works just fine - so why bother with another approach?

Comment: It's funny, I interviewed at Microsoft back in 2008 or so, and I got a series of hierarchy-related questions from a pair of junior devs, who seemed quite frustrated that I wrote the first answer on the whiteboard using a recursive CTE, then adjusted it slightly by one or two lines as their questions got progressively "harder." I don't think they were expecting someone to be able to solve the problem using recursive CTEs, and so that portion of the interview lasted 5 minutes instead of 30. They were dejected. Is your "no CTE" goal part of an interview question by any chance?

Comment: I always find these questions funny. Why would you ever want to do something without using the built-in solution designed to handle that something? To me, It seems just like asking how to create your own auto-increment mechanism (Hint: Don't). There is a solution. It's designed to solve this very specific problem. It's built and tested by the same people that built the entire database. Why would you think there is a better way to do it?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Right. Or, at least, make the question realistic, like what would you use in place of identity (or how would you protect identity) if avoiding gaps is crucial. Don't just ask, "How would you do this without identity?" without explaining why identity isn't suitable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I never find these kind of questions funny. For two simple reasons: 1) I have to work with multiple RDBMSes and it allows to broaden the perspective 2) Second even within SQL Server 2014 when Hekaton (in-memory) was introduced, we had to find solution for cases that was easily solved in T-SQL, but not available in native compiled procedures. I don't ask "why"(when constraints are set - the correct question is "how").

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Granted, sometimes you have to come up with solutions that will enable you to work with multiple RDBMSes or other restrictions, but that's just sometimes. Most of the times that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTE allows to solve this kind of recursive queries. If you know depth level in advance you could "unwind" recursive part:

```
SELECT p0.ProductId, p0.ParentProductID, 0 AS ProductLevel
FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p0
WHERE p0.ParentProductId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT p1.ProductId, p1.ParentProductID, 1 AS ProductLevel
FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p1
JOIN (SELECT p0.ProductId, p0.ParentProductID, 0 AS ProductLevel
      FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p0
      WHERE p0.ParentProductId IS NULL) p0
  ON p1.ParentProductId = p0.ProductId
UNION ALL
SELECT p2.ProductId, p2.ParentProductID, 2 AS ProductLevel
FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p2
JOIN (SELECT p1.ProductId, p1.ParentProductID, 1 AS ProductLevel
      FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p1
      JOIN (SELECT p0.ProductId, p0.ParentProductID, 0 AS ProductLevel
      FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p0
      WHERE p0.ParentProductId IS NULL) p0
        ON p1.ParentProductId = p0.ProductId) p1
  ON p2.ParentProductId = p1.ProductId
UNION ALL
SELECT p3.ProductId, p3.ParentProductID, 3 AS ProductLevel
FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p3
JOIN  (SELECT p2.ProductId, p2.ParentProductID, 2 AS ProductLevel
       FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p2
       JOIN (SELECT p1.ProductId, p1.ParentProductID, 1 AS ProductLevel
             FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p1
             JOIN (SELECT p0.ProductId, p0.ParentProductID, 0 AS ProductLevel
                    FROM [dbo].[ProductHierarchy] p0
                    WHERE p0.ParentProductId IS NULL) p0
              ON p1.ParentProductId = p0.ProductId) p1
        ON p2.ParentProductId = p1.ProductId) p2
  ON p3.ParentProductId = p2.ProductId;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b29fa0a4471a38014ea76e92e1972cc)**